# Meteor Alternative to Aggregate Stats?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm looking to do $avg (aggregation) on my collection, Meteor doesn't support it. The solution are only static and not reactive, or to use a forEach loop. Which is really not good for performance. I think my only way will be to hold it on separated collection like "stats". But how should it work, How is it calculated and stored and used? Anyone have any experience and great solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question! 
There are packages to enable you to use the aggregation pipeline such as
https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/
but like you said they aren't reactive.

Perhaps you could setup an [cursor.observeChanges](http://devdocs.io/meteor/index#observe_changes) on the relevant collections, or tracker.autorun, but that could result in a lot of code running that takes longer to finish than the next change coming in, so you get a backlog of events.

I think the better way is like you say to have a separate stats collection that runs regularly. do you really need realtime updates, or just something like once per minute?

There are some event queue tools like 
https://github.com/artwells/meteor-queue
that could help with that.

Good luck!

Comment: I guess something with meteor-queue should work, And synced cron. Too bad it's so complicate to show just the average number.